# PHP - How to get "upper" key from value in a nested array?

Tags: php

```
$arrayTypesAndSubtypes = Account::getTypesAndSubtypes();
$subtype = $request->input('subtype');
```

Here's a *dd* of *$arrayTypesAndSubtypes* from which I want to get the **"*upper (?)* key"** for a given value.

```
array:2 [▼
  "REVENUE" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "REVENUE"
  ]
  "ASSET" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "BANK_ACCOUNT"
  ]
]
```

Here, the following returns false (because *Array_search()* will return **0** for either *REVENUE* or *BANK_ACCOUNT* ; however, what I'm looking for is to return either **REVENUE** or **ASSET** (what I'm calling the "upper key" - *is there a more proper term for that?*).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `array_keys` probably?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to provide context for how you're interacting with the array?

Comment: _is there a more proper term for that?_ Yes, they are the array keys, and so using `array_keys($array)` you will get back an array with all the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they are in the `0` key, just extract that column, combine with the current keys and search:

```
$key = array_search('BANK_ACCOUNT', array_combine(array_keys($array), 
                                                  array_column($array, 0)));

var_dump(key);  //should return ASSET
```

Or if you have multiple under each key, then loop:

```
$key = false;
foreach($array as $key => $values) {
    if(array_search('BANK_ACCOUNT', $values)) { // or in_array('BANK_ACCOUNT', $values)
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($key);  //should return ASSET
```

Comment: 3rd line, replacing "array_search" by "in_array" suggested as a comment, is what I was looking for. `if(in_array(...)`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could "flatten" your array first using [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map):

```
$flattened = array_map(fn(array $val) => $val[0], $arr));
```

Then simply `array_search` it:

```
$key = array_search('BANK_ACCOUNT', $flattened);  // ASSET
```